# new android Location API - onLocationChaged doesn't get called

Tags: android

I'm having problem using Googles new Location API
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html

I'm writing an application that lists nearbly places based on users location.
90% of the cases my app works well, but sometimes my LocationListener doesn't gets the callback, so I'm suspecting that the device can't find location. 
I only added coarse location permission, so the API only uses network to find location.

I don't want to post the full source, but the basic method is this:

- In the onCreate() method I init a LocationClient field
- In onStart i call locationClient.connect (in onStop disconnect() )
- In the onConnected callback I check if the LocationClient.getLastLocation is not null, if so, I use it, else I call requestLocations.

My method seems to be working, but in some devices onLocationChaged is never called, and I don't know why.
Unfortunately I don't have any of the devices producing this malfunction, so I can't provide any log about the fenomenon, I'm just hoping someone ran into the same issue.
Any help would be much appreciated.